# Infinity while on scanf function

Tags: c

What is wrong with this code? The while loop continues to run even if a '1' or '2' is typed.

```
#include "stdio.h"

void helper(void);
int main() {
    int s;

    scanf("%d", &s);

    while(s!=1 || s!=2) {
        helper();
        scanf("%d", &s);
    }

    return 0;
}

void helper(void) {
    printf("Please use 1 or 2 as option");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any number is either not equal to one **or** not equal to two: you can be certain of that :)

What you probably wanted to write was `&&`.

```
while(s!=1 && s!=2) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant

```
while(s!=1 && s!=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `||` should be a `&&` in your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the || to &&.

Answer (score 1):

Check your condition in while. Any variable can not have two values. So use && instead of ||

Answer (score 1):

```
while(s!=1 || s!=2)
```

translates to:

```
while(s is not 1 OR s is not 2)
```

So if `s` is `1`, it's not `2` ... which means you keep looping.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
while(s!=1 || s!=2) {         helper();         scanf("%d", &s);     }
```

into this:

```
while(s!=1 && s!=2) {         helper();         scanf("%d", &s);     }
```

to work.

Keep coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `||` to `&&`.